# Как вычленить URL источника который приходит в контроллер

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, url

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять одну вещь. Есть сайт в интернете, который, периодически мне на сервер на Java контроллер на Spring, шлёт с сайта JSON с данными.

Подскажите, как мне вычленить URL откуда пришёл JSON и записать этот URL в переменную?

Я понимаю, что могу попросить фронтэнд присылать мне в теле JSON заодно и URL, но это не то)

Comment: Url откуда пришел json? Это как? Вы дергаете какой-то вполне очевидный урл POST /citizents/2322 и туда кидается джсон. Вам надо кто туда отослал или получить /citizents/2322?

Comment: Мне нужно " надо кто туда отослал" ))) Вкратце. Есть сайт, сайт, периодически, мне на сервер с java присылает данные. Мне нужно отловить URL этого сайта

Comment: Это не возможно. Фактически, единственная информация которую можно получить обходными путями(не в джаве вообще) это только IP адрес. Отправляйте сами нужную информацию. В идеале, вы должны регистирровать любой микросервис как пользователя, который потом и делает и запрос. То есть, можно получить информацию и текущем пользователе, который делает запрос, а уж там то и хранится информация о том что это некий сервис, его название, URL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В метод контроллера как параметр можно добавить `HttpServletRequest request` и после из него вытащить URL. Пример:

```
@GetMapping
public void get(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String requestUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать посмотреть заголовок "referer" запроса.

Типа

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
```

> **Заголовок реферера:**
>
> Заголовок HTTP Referer (который случайно ошибочно указан в спецификации HTTP) является необязательным заголовком запроса, который содержит URL-адрес веб-страницы, связанной с запрашиваемым ресурсом.  Обычно он автоматически добавляется браузерами, когда пользователь запускает HTTP-запрос, в том числе путем нажатия ссылки или отправки формы.  Существуют различные методы, которые позволяют ссылочной странице удерживать или изменять значение заголовка Referer.  Часто это делается из соображений конфиденциальности.